# SpringBoot + Liquibase: How generate changelog from model?

Tags: jpa, groovy, spring-boot, liquibase

I need to generate the changelogs based on my model in SpringBoot (JPA). Using the plugin (springboot) **liquibase**, there is a `gradle task` `generateChanglog` that generate changelog.groovy with existing db tables.

I want to generate this changelog from my model, not existing DB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide *referenceUrl* configured to our persistence unit (for example 'hibernate:spring:your.package.with.domain.objects?dialect=your.database.Dialect').

Afterwards you should be able to generate what you need by liquibase **diff** which will compare your current DB state to referenced entities.